# Ignoring RouteValues with MvcSitemapprovider MVC 5 Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container, mvcsitemapprovider

I have an MVC 5 application with Unity DI using the `MvcSiteMapProvider` package from NuGet. I'm trying to use the ignore `MvcSiteMapProvider_AttributesToIgnore` appSetting in my `web.config` file like the following

```
<add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_AttributesToIgnore" value="type" />
```

But when my sitemap is displayed, the urls have the ignored value as the querystring.

There is a section in the `MvcSiteMapProvider` documentation that reads

> If using an external DI container, this setting can be found on the constructor of the ReservedAttributeNameProvider in a parameter named "attributesToIgnore", which is type IEnumerable

I'm using Unity so I wonder if I need to add this to my container somehow, but I don't know how.

Any ideas on how to ignore route values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add the settings to the ReservedAttributeNameProvider as described in the documentation:

```
// Prepare for the sitemap node providers
this.Container.RegisterType<IXmlSource, FileXmlSource>("file1XmlSource", new InjectionConstructor(absoluteFileName));
this.Container.RegisterType<IReservedAttributeNameProvider, ReservedAttributeNameProvider>(
    // Add the attributes to ignore here
    new InjectionConstructor(new string[] { "type", "value2" }));
```

**Tip:** You can always find out what dependencies a class has by temporarily newing up the class and looking at the parameters with Intellisense.

```
new ReservedAttributeNameProvider( 

// Type the above in Visual Studio and you will see the constructor parameters
// in a tooltip
```

Comment: That did the trick. I was trying to add this in the wrong location. I forgot to mention I have the MvcSiteMapProvider MVC5 Unity Modules installed and in that case I should have been trying to make this change in MvcSiteMapProviderContainerExtension class. Thanks.

Comment: I may need to start a new thread, but when I add my attributes to ignore the SiteMapNodeModel.IsCurrentNode and SiteMapNodeModel.IsInCurrentPath are false when they should be true on nodes that have the attribute to ignore set. If the attribute to ignore is left off, these properties work as expected. Any suggestions?

Comment: When a key is set in AttributesToIgnore, it will no longer be part of the route match. That is its purpose - so you can make an attribute that is *not* a route value. It sounds like you are trying to exclude a value that should be included in order to make a route match. It might be worth asking a new question if you are still confused about it, though.

Comment: Just a note: if using Castle Windsor you can set these settings in `MvcSiteMapProviderInstaller`. Worked perfectly here.